# "Out-of-range value" error when converting a varchar to datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, data-conversion

I have this code

```
datecreation = todaydate.Substring(6, 4) + todaydate.Substring(3, 2) + 
                   todaydate.Substring(0, 2) 

string sql = "insert into Usertable ";
sql += "values(" + mVendid + ", '" + usrname + "','" + usrpass + "', cast('" + 
datecreation + "'as DATETIME),'" + createdby + "')";
```

The problem is whenever it is running in server it is giving error. In Local host or in SQL server management it is working fine.

What the heck is it not working whenever it is in the web

> The error is The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data
>   type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Answer (score 4):

Never concatenate string to form SQL queries, always use parameterized query. For your code you can use [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx), with your command. There instead of Converting `DateTime` to string and then casting it back `DateTime` in `INSERT` query , simply add the value of `DateTime` object in parameter. This will not only save you from [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) but also resolves issues like the one you are having.

Something like:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connectionstring"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    string sql = "insert into Usertable ";
    sql += "values(@mVendid, @usrname, @usrpass, @datecreation, @createdby)";
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mVendid", mVendid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrname", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrpass", userpass);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datecreation", Convert.ToDateTime(datecreation));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdby", createdby);
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

if `datecreation` is coming from a `DateTime` object then add that directly, otherwise you can parse it to `DateTime` object and let SQL server handle the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the time zone of the server. Likely that it is a different time zone to your local machine. You can avoid the issue by using parameters.

```
    string sql = @"
INSERT INTO Usertable 
VALUES (@Parameter1, @Parameter2, @Parameter3, @Parameter4, @Parameter5)";

(using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1", mVendid);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter2", usrname);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter3", usrpass);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter4", todaydate);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter5", createdBy);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that probably you server has different language settings that your machine.
To make sure that converting is working you Convert function. Full tutorial is here: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

BTW constructing queries like concatenate string is very dangerous way. Instead of this use SqlParamerts. Moreover advantage using this approach is that .NET will do conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all user parameters (better, clearer and safer!). Second this error happens due to format issues.

```
datecreation = todaydate.Substring(6, 4) + todaydate.Substring(3, 2) + 
               todaydate.Substring(0, 2) 

string date = DateTime.Parse(datecreation);

string sql = "insert into Usertable values(@mvendid, @username, @usrpass, @date, @createdby)";

var con = new SqlConnection(""); // your connection string
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mvendid", mVendid);
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all its really a bad query and quite hacky, you shouldn't be writing query like this

```
string sql = "insert into Usertable ";
sql += "values(" + mVendid + ", '" + usrname + "','" + usrpass + "', cast('" + 
datecreation + "'as DATETIME),'" + createdby + "')";
```

**Always use Paramaterised Queries **

Error might be there because you are converting some text to datetime. Possible reasons Datetime not well formed
Dateimte doesn't matches to your server datetime
Try to print out the exact value what its creating

```
 cast('" + 
    datecreation + "'as DATETIME)
```